# How to get proper search results with wp_query

Tags: wordpress, search

I am using wp_query to get search results. But it only searches and returns matching title only. Does not return matching content and other ACF fields. How can I do that? I am also using "Search everything" plugin in my site. Here the arguments for my wp_query:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => $post_type,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=> $no_of_posts,
        'offset'        => $offset,
        's'             => $query,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem

Prepending a term with a hyphen will exclude posts matching that term.

Eg, 'pillow -sofa' will return posts containing 'pillow' but not 'sofa'.